# How do I determine the SVN working copy layout version?

Tags: svn, working-copy

For example, the SVN 1.5 client has one layout for working copies, and the SVN 1.6 client has a different layout. I understand that the layout automatically gets upgraded when it gets touched by a newer client.

If I have a working copy on my system, how can I find out the version of the layout it's using?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

If `.svn/format` exists, then read the number in it:

- Version 7 is SVN 1.3
- Version 8 is SVN 1.4
- Version 9 is SVN 1.5

If `.svn/format` doesn't exist then the version number is on the first line in `.svn/entries`:

- Version 10 is SVN 1.6
- Version 12 is SVN 1.7

Subversion 1.6 was the first one not to use `.svn/format`. Version 7 and older used XML-based `.svn/entries` file, newer versions use less verbose line-based file format.

Since Subversion 1.7 the version number is stored in the `.svn/wc.db` SQLite database in the "user_version" field. So even though `.svn/format` is bumped to version 12 the actual format version is 29 and future versions may not update `.svn/format` anymore.  To obtain the version number from `.svn/wc.db` there are two methods:

1. if you have `sqlite3` in your path, `sqlite3 .svn/wc.db "PRAGMA user_version"`
2. if you DO NOT have `sqlite3` in your path, open `.svn/wc.db` in a hex editor and read the DWORD at offset 0x3c

All the format version numbers are described in [wc.h](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_wc/wc.h) along with the version numbers of respective Subversion releases.

Comment: My file has format value = 4. This does not make sense. Does it ?

Comment: @ShariqueAbdullah I believe version 4 corresponds to the original Subversion 1.0 release, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @ShariqueAbdullah That sounds more like a repository format version than a remotely modern working copy format version.

Comment: As of Subversion 1.8, this method is sadly broken.

Comment: I've already updated the answer to mention that Subversion 1.7+ stores the version number in the SQLite database (pragma user_version). The link to wc.h also contains the relevant version number for Subversion 1.8.

Comment: link to wc.h is broken now. Do we have a new link?

Answer (score 12):

From Stack Overflow question *[Find out SVN working copy version (1.7 or 1.8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265363)*:

One can use `sqlite3 .svn/wc.db "PRAGMA user_version"` on SVN 1.7 or later (or `od -An -j63 -N1 -t dC .svn/wc.db` if you only have the [SQLite 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite#History) libraries, YMMV).

Comment: The `od` command works on my system which I believe lacks the SQLite libraries. Thanks!