# How to avoid the exception when I update the last version from SVN Client?

Tags: svn, controls, version

Platform : Visual Studio 2010 + AnkhSVN plugin. Or TortoiseSVN in Windows Explorer.
Server : VisualSVN Server free version + Windows Server 2003 x64.
Problem:

1. I use the VS2010 to edit my code with our team, I choose the multi-user mode of SVN to host my project. I usually encounter the error : "one or more of your local resources are out of date....", I can't "update to lastest version".
2. If my workmate change a file and check in it, I want to update my local file. The same file can't to update to lastest version. I had better to delete my file in windows explorer, then go to its parent folder to update to get the new one. It's uneffective.
3. When I have a conflit in a file, I want to merge my file with the HEAD version in the project. But I don't know how to do. The merge function look like only support folder branch, doesn't support file merge.

Answer (score 1):

When a conflict arise, you are better [resolving](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve) it when it raise. To resolve a conflict, you should edit the conflicted files using a diff tool to make sure you have all the good code. Also you should remove every line in the files that has these character `<<` `>>`. When your files is ok, you should run `svn resolved` on the file, and then proceed with your work.

Hope this help.

Comment: Could you please update the link reference to a reference of documentation from the Subversion Book that is not over six years old?  The search engines have a nasty habit of returning out date references for the Subversion book at red-bean.com.

Comment: @jgifford25, Sorry I didn't see the version. It is now updated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running multiple subversion clients it could be that you're mixing different versions of subversion code under the covers: different versions of Subversion use [different working copy formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364618/how-do-i-determine-svn-working-copy-layout-version) on disk. For example if your AnkhSVN is based on Subversion 1.5 and your Tortoise on 1.6 then if you use Tortoise on an AnhkSVN checkout then it will upgrade it to 1.6 format and you will no longer be able to use your 1.5 AnkhSVN to update it.

You should make sure you're running versions of both AnkhSVN and Tortoise with the same minor Subversion number under the covers, ideally 1.6.x.