# non-digit file error

Tags: macos, svn, smartsvn

I am trying to update to head revision using smartsvn v6 professional version. I am getting this error

```
Update to Head: First line of '/folders/.svn/entries' contains non-digit file '/folders/.svn/format' does not exist
```

How to fix the above error?

I got this error most of the times. To solved this I need to create new folder and checkout whole project there then it works. But thats not the preferred way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use the command line version of subversion client? Or any client besides smartsvn?

i think this happen when you mix different workcopy version.

To check your workcopy version, see this question: [How do I determine the SVN working copy layout version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364618/how-do-i-determine-svn-working-copy-layout-version)

Comment: Yes I got this problem when someone else (using tortoise-svn) is committing new files.

Comment: I guess your tortoise-svn is newer then your smartsvn --- it upgrade your repository when you use it. Check smartsvn and see if they have newer version. If not, you have no option but checkout from server again.