# Find out SVN working copy version (1.7 or 1.8)

Tags: svn

How can I find out the working copy version (SVN 1.7 vs. 1.8) by taking a look at files inside `.svn` without using any SVN tool?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Determine SVN Working Copy Layout Version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364618/how-do-i-determine-svn-working-copy-layout-version)

Comment: A more general answer to this question already exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364618/how-do-i-determine-svn-working-copy-layout-version

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How do I determine the SVN working copy layout version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364618)*.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as the question linked above (thrice) does not cover 1.7 vs 1.8 - except for an answer that backlinks to this question.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I was wondering about this myself for a while and couldn't find an answer anywhere, not even by looking at the SQLite database. So I ended up looking into the Subversion source code, where I found that the version is indeed stored in the database, I just wasn't looking in the right place. Here's the relevant snippet from [`subversion/libsvn_subr/sqlite.c`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_subr/sqlite.c):

```
svn_error_t *
svn_sqlite__read_schema_version(int *version,
                                svn_sqlite__db_t *db,
                                apr_pool_t *scratch_pool)
{
  (...)
  SVN_ERR(prepare_statement(&stmt, db, "PRAGMA user_version;", scratch_pool));
  (...)
}
```

I wasn't even aware of the `PRAGMA` statement, which, according to the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) is...

> ...an SQL extension specific to SQLite and used to modify the operation of the SQLite library or to query the SQLite library for internal (non-table) data.

Thus, assuming a reasonably up-to-date version of SQLite on the `PATH` you can do...

```
sqlite3 .svn/wc.db "PRAGMA user_version"
```

...in the root of your working copy, which will then yield e.g. `29` for Subversion 1.7.13 and `31` for Subversion 1.8.0. Unfortunately there seems to be no list correlating `user_version` to the Subversion version, but if you're interested in what the format changes actually consist of, you can find them described in the sources in [`subversion/libsvn_wc/wc-metadata.sql`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_wc/wc-metadata.sql) for format 20 onwards.

**Update 1:** Addressing the question of how to retrieve the value of `user_version` without an SQLite executable: You need to read a `DWORD` at offset `60` in the database file, as specified in the [SQLite file format specification](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html) (see "1.2 The Database Header").

**Update 2:** To clarify further how to view it in a text/binary file viewer: Since the current version numbers are still pretty low and fit in a single byte (i.e. they're smaller than `255`) and a `DWORD` is four bytes long, it's sufficient at the moment to look at the least significant byte - which is byte number `64`. Below is a screenshot of how it looks like in a Subversion 1.8.0 working copy's SQLite database file, which carries `31` for `user_version` - as already mentioned above.

[image: Subversion 1.8.0 SQLite database in Text viewer]

**Update 3:** I was always looking for a way to do such "binary queries" with a command-line tool, to avoid throwing perl or such at the problem. [Turns out there's a *nix utility for that called `od`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html) (and I even got it in my collection of win32 ports, yay!). `od` can get the least significant byte of `user_version` like this:

```
od -An -j63 -N1 -t dC .svn/wc.db
```

This will again output `31` for Subversion 1.8.0 and so on.

Answer (score 18):

If .svn/format exists, then read the number in it:

```
Version 7 is SVN 1.3
Version 8 is SVN 1.4
Version 9 is SVN 1.5
```

If .svn/format doesn't exist then the version number is on the first line in .svn/entries:

```
Version 10 is SVN 1.6
Version 12 is SVN 1.7
```

Comment: That's what I've tried, but it looks like my SVN 1.7 and SVN 1.8 working copies both show version 12.

Comment: @ThomasS. are you sure about both working copy are different SVN ?

Comment: They are, the format was changed from 1.7 to 1.8, and they are incompatible to each other.

Answer (score -4):

Can't find documentation on this so far, however the short answer is -- you can. Peek into `\.svn\format` file. For example, number `12` there means that the working copy is of SVN 1.8 format. I assume that if it's of SVN 1.7, then you'll see `11` there.

Comment: -1 Nope that's not it - just tried it with Subversion 1.7.13 vs 1.8.0 and they both output `12` in the `format` file.

Comment: OK, but that still doesn't help distinguishing a 1.7 from a 1.8 WC - which is what the question was about. You cannot operate on a 1.7 WC with 1.8 and vice versa.