# Idea couldn't recognise format of subversion

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I have such notificaton in IDEA 12

Root 'D:/myproject' is likely to be of unsupported Subversion format

And such error on trying to update from IDEA 12

Error updating changes: svn: E155021: The client is too old to work with the working copy at "..." (format 31).

I've checked out sources with commandline client v 1.8.5

It creates working copy with format/entries 12. (it is 1.7 I suppose) IDEA 12 supports 1.7 subversion

What could cause such problem?

Answer (score 2):

There's your answer:

> I've checked out sources with commandline client v 1.8.5

Working copies that were created using `svn` 1.8+ cannot be used at all with any `svn` client 1.7 or less. You need to either use another command line client or do the checkout using IDEA.

Comment: What command did you use for the checkout? If you used a 1.8 client and issued something like `svn checkout xxx`, it will be a 1.8 working copy.

Comment: Well, then it will be a 1.8 working copy, and not readable by IDEA. The `format` file was only used up to version `1.7` I think, after that the actual version number of the wc layout can be found as described in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19272304/1329844

Comment: Agreed. SVN 1.8 is supported only since IDEA 13. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20797443/579828)