# How can I determine the version of a SVN working copy using SVN tools?

Tags: svn

There's a related question about finding the version **without** using SVN tools: [Find out SVN working copy version (1.7 or 1.8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265363/find-out-svn-working-copy-version-1-7-or-1-8). That's not very straightforward though, so assuming it's OK to use the SVN tools, is there a simpler way? `svn info` does not report the the version of the working copy.

Comment: Generally (at least with 1.7 and up), the tools only work with a current version of working copy format, and will either tell you to update (if the WC version is old) or refuse to work or give an error (if the WC version is newer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type .svn\format`

Can't test 1.7 WC, but it must differ from `12.` of 1.8+ WCs

**Sample**

```
>svn co URL
...
Checked out revision 7.

>svn --version
svn, version 1.8.8 (r1568071)
   compiled Feb 18 2014, 20:10:29 on x86-microsoft-windows
...

>type z:\trunk\.svn\format
12
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. So it's not possible to do this with the SVN tools. One must figure out the details of how each version is stored internally.