# After Delphi XE5 update 2 ie:reinstall , Subversion access has been lost

Tags: delphi, svn, delphi-xe5

Specifically if I reopen an old Delphi project (already on subversion repository), right clicking in PM I find *Add to version control*. If I try that I get an error

> ..cannot find file libapr-1.dll

I think the subversion Delphi integration has lost the correct path to SVN config, as the file exist in the CollabNet folder.

I did an update of CollabNet Subversion Client in the hope of restoring the environmental variable, with no success.

That's my first time I got SVN problems therefore I am confused on what to do to recover SVN use.

Comment: "right clicking in PM"  what ??? /// i guess you try SysInternals Process Monitor, filter logs be "path" "containing" "libapr-1" and do those clicks again. Then you would see which program searches for the lib and reinstall it

Comment: @Arioch'The No. PM = Delphi Project Manager

Comment: @DavidHeffernan funny, i meant he SHOULD try Process Monitor, did not noticed it also is PM. While topicstarter might mean Project Manager, he also might mean whatever else. Don't want to guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Delphi IDE's Subversion integration needs to know where to find the Subversion DLLs. It does so using a registry value. That value is under this key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\12.0\Subversion
```

And the value is a `REG_SZ` value named `SvnDllDir`. That should contain the full path to the directory that contains the Subversion DLLs. For instance, on my machine it is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin
```

But obviously you'll need to use the correct path for your local installation. You do also need to make sure that you use a build of Subversion that is compatible with the Delphi IDE integration. Not all Subversion builds are.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt answer. I got all your points and will follow.

Comment: After creating the registry entry (it was lacking) SvnDllDir, with the correct Path, I got a different error msg about ".. This Client is too old to work with the working copy at.."

Comment: That's a quite different problem. The fact that you have got that message indicates that I have already answered your question. What you need to do is to make sure that the working copy version of your repo matches the SVN version you are using.

Comment: Thanks David, that was clear to me too. As, despite I have used "SVN Upgrade working copy" rightclick context on some projects file, without resolving the issue; can you help me on how to find out versions difference between old and new one ? I appreciate your time devoted to help me.

Comment: Well, you know the version of the the SVN client that you installed. That's the thing that the reg setting in my answer points to. The working copy version is found following instructions here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364618/how-do-i-determine-svn-working-copy-layout-version) I think you should not be attempting to upgrade your working copy until you know more. Finally, is your repo local, or is it served?

Comment: I agree totally to stop doing up untill made a version inventory. My repo is on external drive. Thanks

Comment: Hi, just a mess. The SVN Client is ver. 1.7.14-1, while the svn/format on the repository shows 5, i.e. I think prior vers 1.3.

Comment: Hi, just a mess. The SVN Client is ver. 1.7.14-1, while the svn/format on the repository shows 5, i.e. I think prior vers 1.3. Now, last bothering, please give me your advice on what to do: My repository hosts about 15 projects. I am available also to reset everything and rebuild it, but I like to hear from you. Thanks again